# Compactness in Topology

Tags: general-topology

What is the scope and idea behind Compact Spaces in Topology?

Considering that the basic topics in Topology is covered using the book by Munkres

Comment: It is a natural generalization of "bounded and closed" in more general spaces that $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @N.H. Rather it is a great generalization of finite